# AWS IAM Policy To Restrict S3 Access (Prefix) Based On IAM User's Tag

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, policy

A variety of IAM users are sharing access to an S3 bucket. The S3 bucket has content separated by user so each user has a unique area they have access to.

For instance:

- S3 Bucket: `example-bucket`.
- IAM User: `UserOne`. This user is tagged with `sampleTag=u11111`.
- IAM User: `UserTwo`. This user is tagged with `sampleTag=u22222`.
- Many more tagged IAM users.

I'd like to write an IAM policy such that:

- `UserOne` has access to read+write content to `s3://example-bucket/u11111/*` and read content from `s3://example-bucket/config/u11111/`
- `UserTwo` has access to read+write content to `s3://example-bucket/u22222/*` and read content from `s3://example-bucket/config/u22222/`
- Etc...

Note that the S3 key includes the value of the `sampleTag` in the path.

I'd like this single policy to be able to be applied to the entire group of IAM users without need to include an individual policy for each user.

I expected this to be possible thanks to `${aws:PrincipalTag/sampleTag}` which I thought would inject the tag value in that location in the resource strings. But after playing with the policy simulator, it doesn't seem to accomplish this.

Current policy looks like:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket-test"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "${aws:PrincipalTag/sampleTag}/"
                    ],
                    "s3:delimiter": ["/"]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket-test"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": ["${aws:PrincipalTag/sampleTag}/*"]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/config/${aws:PrincipalTag/sampleTag}/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket-test/config/${aws:PrincipalTag/sampleTag}/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/${aws:PrincipalTag/sampleTag}/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket-test/${aws:PrincipalTag/sampleTag}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I think the last two policies to not work. I can't find documentation to say if you can embed variables into the `Resource` strings or not, but `s3:prefix` doesn't seem to be available for `GetObject` or `PutObject` operations -- so I'm not sure how else to restrict the scope of those permissions.

Any ideas as to what is wrong or how to accomplish this would be appreciated!

Comment: You should consider doing this by username (${aws:username}), not by tags. See https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-s3-user-specific-folder/

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-tags confirms that it should be possible to use IAM user tags within the `Resource` string. It's difficult to debug because the Policy Simulator (https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/) just says no rules match (default denied) rather than explain the evaluation process. --- I cannot use username as suggested above, this is for existing data structured in this way that cannot be rearranged into directories matching usernames.

Comment: I do not believe that you can use `PrincipalTag` in a `Resource`. You can in the `Condition` statement.

Comment: You definitely can use `aws:PrincipalTag/*` in `Resource` strings. As I mentioned above, it is in the official documentation (last item before the `Condition Element`) section of that link.

I'm actually pretty sure the policy I posted works fine. I'm part way into testing at the moment, but all indications are that the IAM Policy Simulator is just broken/doesn't support it because the same actions take by the authenticated user outside the simulator are allowed rather than denied.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible to use ${aws:PrincipalTag} in the Ressource property of a policy. Just look into the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-wheretouse) of IAM. The example uses the PrincipalTag as last part of the Ressource value.

(Just use Strg + F and type PrincipalTag on the docs website an you find the example)

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the last two policies will not work.

According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_condition-keys.html#condition-keys-service-available) `aws:PrincipalTag/tag-key` *works with [string operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements_condition_operators.html#Conditions_String)*, hence `aws:PrincipalTag/tag-key` usage will only works inside `Condition` policy elements.

Also, `s3:prefix` condition key only work for `ListBucket` & `ListBucketVersions` actions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html#amazons3-policy-keys

Answer (score 0):

You can have PrincipalTag as part of the resource.
This works.

```
    {
        "Sid": "FullPermissionOnlyForPrefix",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:PrincipalTag/team}*",
            "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/${aws:PrincipalTag/team}/*"
        ]
    }
```